# vue chart.js линейный график плохо видны элементы из за большой разницы значений

Tags: javascript, vue.js, диаграммы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такой график, но из за большой разницы между данными остальных линий практически не видно

`1 => 800 000 2 => 30 000  3 => 1 000  4 => 20`

Подскажите какие решения есть?